# Onvif playback stream cannot seek

Tags: playback, seek, onvif

I'm trying to obtain playback video streams from some Axis and Hikvision cameras, using Onvif. 
I'm doing this in a C# application, and the resulted stream is played in VLC.

Using the FindRecordings/GetRecordingSearchResult calls and then GetReplayUri I can obtain the playback stream (RTSP/H264), but here I have this problem: this behaves like a live stream - I can only use play and pause. I cannot use the time cursor to seek, cannot play in reverse.

So I find this unusable for a playback application - you have to watch the entire recording (days or hours of recording!) in order to see a specific event in time. And once you play it, you cannot go back 1 minute to see it again.

This seems quite stupid to me, so I believe that I'm doing something wrong in my code. Maybe I'm missing some configuration in order to obtain a 'true' playback stream.

My question is: is this playback stream behavior the 'standard' one, and I cannot expect more on this? Or some of you have this working ok (seek, reverse, frame by frame stepping), so I will know it can be done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse playback is possible, but it is not easy. First, the reverse replay is  initiated  using the Scale header field with a negative  value. As an example:

```
PLAY rtsp://192.168.0.1/path/to/recording RTSP/1.0 
Cseq: 123 
Session: 12345678
Require: onvif-replay 
Range: clock=20090615T114900.440Z-
Rate-Control: no 
Scale: -1.0
```

After the stream is initialized, you will get GOPs in reverse order, not just reversed frames. I don't know if VLC supports this way of operating.

Be aware that only devices with the ReversePlayback  capability support reverse playback.

Please refer to the [streaming specification](https://www.onvif.org/specs/stream/ONVIF-Streaming-Spec-v1712.pdf) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real solution to the problem above, but maybe it would help others to deal with this situation.

Some cameras with which I worked were continuously recording on the same video file (so the time range was not known) and they were reporting (via RTSP) the available time interval like this:

range:npt=0-

Due to this, VLC was not displaying any time interval in the time slider, so it was not 
allowing for seek. In my case, it was a requirement to use VLC, so I had to find a workaround to the problem. 
This was a module which was acting like a proxy, and it sit between VLC and the RTSP source (camera). So all RTSP traffic between VLC and camera was going via this module which I controlled, so I could easily change the responses from camera in a way which was ok for VLC, so I got the seek capability available in VLC.

Comment: _This is not a real solution to the problem above_, I am sorry to say that, but then it does not belong here.

Comment: I agree, but please note that the initial question was based on the assumption that VLC deals correctly which such situations (when the playback interval is not properly reported by camera). I cannot say this a problem/bug of VLC, but anyway, it makes it unusable for playing playback streams in this conditions. So I consider the approach I described as 'solution' to this, was a reasonable workaround to the problem, which worked in my case.

Comment: Then please rephrase your answer and also add this explanation.