# how to retrieve recorded video from onvif device (IP camera) with specified date range? [C#]

Tags: c#, vlc, onvif

I'm trying to retrieve playback video from onvif device with time range.
I implement code to get replay uri according to 
[Retrieving Recorded Video from an ONVIF Device](http://pdn.pelco.com/blog/retrieving-recorded-video-onvif-device#sthash.fHM61YlV.kyml8HAd.dpbs).

1. GetServices
2. GetRecordingSummary
3. FindRecordings
4. GetRecordingSearchResults
5. GetReplayUri
   Then, I got replyUri from Onvif Camera(Axis,Hikvision) that provide the whole record (startDate to CurrentDate).
   Now, I try to take the playback video (with specified date range).
   According to [XProtect VMS: Manage video playback](https://www.milestonesys.com/globalassets/techcomm/ltsb/provms/english-united-states/index.htm?toc.htm?65734.htm),
   we can manage playback video using vlc wrapper.
   For me, vlc wrapper can not manage even rate speed(vlcplayer.Rate *= 2) of that uri video.

If you have any advice, please share me.

ReplayUri => rtsp://ipaddress:554/Streaming/Tracks/101?transportmode=unicast&replaymode=onvifreplay

similar problem questions are : 
1. [Get stream URI for each recording returned by Onvif Bridge](https://developer.milestonesys.com/s/question/0D50O00003X0yi3SAB/get-stream-uri-for-each-recording-returned-by-onvif-bridge)
2. [How to playback recorded video using Milestone Onvif Bridge](https://developer.milestonesys.com/s/question/0D50O00003EIs1DSAT/how-to-playback-recorded-video-using-milestone-onvif-bridge?t=1501678728135)
3. [Onvif playback stream cannot seek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025449/onvif-playback-stream-cannot-seek)

Answer (score 1):

VLC can do trick play but it will always start at the first available packet. Not many clients properly support ONVIF Profile G but there is one available online called "Happy Times Onvif Client" that should be able to do proper playback with rate control and from a specified point in the stream.

Comment: Yes, I will check it first. Thank you.